# Need to to control JQuery Ui slider as a seekbar for HTML5 video

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to control html5 video for seekbar. I am using Jquery Ui slider. I am using a play button to start this video. But dont understand how to update seekbar with video time?

My code :
HTML :

```
<video class="vdo" width="700" id="videoShow" style="margin-bottom: 4px;" ng-src="videos/test.mp4" >
</video>
<div id="master" style="width:700;height:8px;"></div>
<span id="changeTOpause"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true" onclick="playVideo()"></span>
```

JQuery:

```
function playVideo()
{
    videoShow.play();
}
$('#master').slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 0,
        max: parseInt(video.duration, 10),
        value: 0,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            video.currentTime = ui.value;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check out this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972178/detect-when-the-jquery-ui-slider-is-being-moved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution which works for me :

```
function playVideo()
    {
        videoShow.play();
    }

    $('#videoShow').on({
        canplaythrough: function() {
            var video = this;
            $('#master').slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 0,
                max: parseInt(video.duration, 10),
                value: 0,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    video.currentTime = ui.value;
                }
            });
        },
        timeupdate: function() {
            $('#master').slider('value', this.currentTime)
        }
    });
```